# uploading files from headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-chromedriver

I have such an element that allows me to upload a file by clicking:

```html
<a class="gray_box" href="#">Choose world folder<span>Select the world folder, we'll do the rest</span></a>
```

The problem is that when clicked, it calls the file manager
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cdmx.png)

first I did the download like this:

```py
import pyautogui

button = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href='#']"))).click()

pyautogui.write(<path>)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

but this does not allow me to upload the file in headless mode

because the path is inserted directly into the console and the ["confirmation window"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTriV.png) is called, which has to be confirmed manually

how do I make a file upload to work in headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files with Selenium is done by sending the uploaded file full path string to a special element. This element can be located with the following XPath `"//input[@type='file']"` or in CSS Selector style `"input[type='file']"`.
So, if the file you wish to upload is for example "C:\my_folder\the_file.png" it can be uploaded with Selenium with the following code line:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys("C:\my_folder\the_file.png")
```

Comment: but it doesn't work because there is no input element on the page [screenshot](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/981096164130693141/1017512920499900476/2022-09-08-221148_276x104_scrot.png)

Comment: that's strange. I never saw a web page performing file uploads without such file. It can contain multiple elements matching this locator on a single page, but always at least 1 should be... Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: sure [chunker.app](https://chunker.app)

Comment: Really strange... I have no solution for that. At least not right now

Answer (score 0):

Some websites request a user agent in headless mode, edit this argument in your work and try again.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: it breaks everything in general [screenshot](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/981096164130693141/1017690437886160896/2022-09-09-095631_1229x1034_scrot.png?width=681&height=579)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.get('https://chunker.app/#')

button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href='#']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.write(path+Keys.ENTER)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

This currently goes through that in nonheadless so far haven't tested headless. It was about 4 enters in total.

Comment: this method simply cancels the download by pressing "cancel"
I tried like this, but it didn't help either
```python
button = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
  (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href='#']"))).click()


time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.write(os.getcwd() + '/' + output_world_name + Keys.ENTER)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('tab')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```